# How do I ignore changes to everything for an ec2 instance except a certain attribute?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a terraform configuration for an already deployed EC2 instance. I want to change the instance type alone for this instance. I want something like this :

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami           =  "ami-09a4a9ce71ff3f20b"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      <everything except instance_type> 
    ]
  } 
}
```

How do I ignore changes to everything for an ec2 instance except a certain attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to do this while the state of the resource does not match the existing state. However I have tested that it is possible, but you need to do the operation in stages... starting with telling terraform what the *current* state of that ec2 instance is and working from there.

**Step 1: Create a Resource Block for The ec2 Instance as it Currently Exists**

I would do this with a combination of manual entry (yes, tedious I know) and utilsing [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html).

You can run `terraform plan` a bunch of times until it reveals no changes on the resource, which would indicate that the resource now matches the current state of the resource.

**Step 2. Update the Block With the New Instance Type**

Once they are equal, it would then be a matter of simply updating the `aws_instance` resource block to your desired `instance_type`.

**Step 3. Apply the Changes to the EC2 Instance in a Targeted Way**

To ensure that only changes to this instance are applied, you can lean on the [terraform apply -target](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting) command to target applying just for this resource specifically. This will void any other resources updating in your plan.

**Step 4. Make Further Adjustments as Required**

Once the resource is now matching the instance you want. Go ahead and modify the rest of the resource block to reflect future state changes.

Comment: Instead of manually entering each attribute by utilising `terraform plan` , I made a list of attributes that terraform `aws_instance` takes except the instance type and I added them in the `ignore changes` of the lifecycle block. What do you think of this approach?